# Need help for the summation of time varying variable in terms of time varying variables and a constant

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Let's say I have a time varying variable, $b_{t}.$
If $z_{t} = \min(c, b_{t})$, for $t = 1 \ldots T.$
Can I say anything about $\sum^{T}_{t = 1} z_{t}$ ? (Any Inequalities, upper bound ,lower bound etc)

Comment: Thank you Luis Felipe for formatting it.

Comment: Clearly, $\sum^{T}_{t = 1} z_{t}\le\min\{Tc, \sum^{T}_{t = 1} b_{t}\}$. I’m afraid it is hard to say more without additional information about $b_t$’s